# Flask-Login trying to change my user.id into random strings instead of established ints?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-security

Since updating my Flask app's dependencies, my Sentry is logging errors I don't understand. Changes to Flask-Login or Flask-Security-Too have thrown me off.

**My user model has always used an Integer as its `primary_key`**

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
(psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: "5818f9aad20447b1b6a37c51f2c2xxxx"
LINE 3: WHERE "user".id = '5818f9aad20447b1b6a37c51f2c2xxxx'
```

Which I assume stems from Flask-Security-Too's datastore user lookup:

```
def find_user(self, **kwargs):
    return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
```

But maybe the problem goes bath further to Flask-Login as it's getting this random ID from the session:

```
    # Load user from Flask Session
    user_id = session.get("_user_id")
    if user_id is not None and self._user_callback is not None:
        user = self._user_callback(user_id)
```

Is Flask-Security-Too's `fs_uniquifier` in my session? Is that what's stepping into the place of my integer ID? I'm hoping I can avoid refactoring my entire code and database and retain my `user.id` as an int. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Here is the full trace that has occurred 15 times since upgrading, all without halting users from accessing or submitting data:

```
InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for integer: "63b93cd01b8f4e65a7daa83becc3xxxx"
LINE 3: WHERE "user".id = '63b93cd01b8f4e65a7daa83becc3xxxx' 
                          ^

  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for integer: "63b93cd01b8f4e65a7daa83becc3xxxx"
LINE 3: WHERE "user".id = '63b93cd01b8f4e65a7daa83becc3xxxx' 
                          ^

[SQL: SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".school_id AS user_school_id, "user".location_id AS user_location_id, "user".first_name AS user_first_name, "user".last_name AS user_last_name, "user".display_name AS user_display_name, "user".image AS user_image, "user".email AS user_email, "user".password AS use...
  File "flask/app.py", line 2463, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "flask/app.py", line 1760, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "flask/app.py", line 1756, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "flask/app.py", line 2247, in preprocess_request
    rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
  File "flask_principal.py", line 477, in _on_before_request
    identity = loader()
  File "flask_security/core.py", line 245, in _identity_loader
    if not isinstance(current_user._get_current_object(), AnonymousUserMixin):
  File "werkzeug/local.py", line 516, in _get_current_object
    return get_name(local())  # type: ignore
  File "flask_login/utils.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "flask_login/utils.py", line 372, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "flask_login/login_manager.py", line 364, in _load_user
    user = self._user_callback(user_id)
  File "flask_security/core.py", line 221, in _user_loader
    return _security.datastore.find_user(id=user_id)
  File "flask_security/datastore.py", line 254, in find_user
    return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2819, in first
    return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 332, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
InFailedSqlTransaction: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

[SQL: SELECT "user".id AS user_id, "user".school_id AS user_school_id, "user".location_id AS user_location_id, "user".first_name AS user_first_name, "user".last_name AS user_last_name, "user".display_name AS user_display_name, "user".image AS user_image, "user".email AS user_email, "user".password AS user_password, "user".fs_uniquifier AS user_fs_uniquifier, "user".phone AS user_phone...
  File "flask/app.py", line 2486, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "flask/app.py", line 2466, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "__init__.py", line 271, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "flask/app.py", line 1662, in handle_exception
    server_error = self.ensure_sync(handler)(server_error)
  File "__init__.py", line 21, in crash_page
    return render_template('error_pages/500.html'), 500
  File "flask/templating.py", line 147, in render_template
    return _render(app, template, context)
  File "flask/templating.py", line 128, in _render
    app.update_template_context(context)
  File "flask/app.py", line 932, in update_template_context
    context.update(func())
  File "flask_login/utils.py", line 407, in _user_context_processor
    return dict(current_user=_get_user())
  File "flask_login/utils.py", line 372, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "flask_login/login_manager.py", line 364, in _load_user
    user = self._user_callback(user_id)
  File "flask_security/core.py", line 221, in _user_loader
    return _security.datastore.find_user(id=user_id)
  File "flask_security/datastore.py", line 254, in find_user
    return self.user_model.query.filter_by(**kwargs).first()
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2819, in first
    return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2903, in _iter
    result = self.session.execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 332, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

Comment: It's so strange. While errors are being recorded, the site appears to still be working. Looks like Flask-Login is pulling an encrypted string from the user's cookie which freaks Postgres out as the user.id can't be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some additional info - as of FS2 3.4.0 it no longer references user.id at all - so that can be whatever you want. FS2 overrides flask_login's UserMixin::get_id - and returns the value of fs_uniquifier. And yes - that is what is stored in the session cookie - and no - nothing in the session cookie is encrypted (it is signed).
So: 1) are you overriding get_id()?
2) any chance that since it seems to be 'working' that you have some post-processing - maybe in a signal or something and it is calling the find_user or some other DB query?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've edited my message to include the raw traceback. I have not overridden `get_id`.

Comment: You appear to be using a very old Flask-Security-Too - 3.0.1! Yes, that still uses your DB model 'id' column (and that is stored in the session cookie).

Comment: I was on Flask-Security-Too v. 4.1.5. However, I found I still had Flask-Security v. 3.0.1. When I removed that, my app broke: `ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore' from 'flask_security' (unknown location)`
Studying up on that now. Thanks for your continued support ✊

Comment: Does Flask-Security need to be installed to run FS2? Are there perhaps any examples of Flask-Security-Too that I might reference? I'm afraid I've gotten myself quite turned around.

Comment: You need to uninstall Flask-Security - if you still see a backtrace with find_user(id=user_id) then you still have something wrong. FS2 is a replacement - it has the same package name Flask-Security. I would pip uninstall flask_security flask_security_too and then re-install pip install flask_security_too

Comment: Ugh! That was it. Thank you for the support.